# in nodejs, how to limit the number of simultaneous access to part of the code?

Tags: node.js

One part of my code, I want it run once simultaneous, no parallel running.

I found semaphore:

```
var sem = require('semaphore')(1);
sem.take(function(){
//xxxxxxxx
sem.leave()
})
```

If I do this, it seems the code between sem.take and sem.leave will be only executed once simultaneously. But is there other way to do this? Cause as a node user, I am not very happy to touch this sort of "multithread" thing.

My problem is the following code, I want them to be run only once simultaneously. But this function can take up to 10 seconds cause I am waiting for the response of run_cmd (basically a wrapped child.exec). 
But if I refreshed the page. Two processes will run silmutaneously. And the stdout from the previous process can affect the coming process.

How to solve this?

```
on.connnection(){
    async function(){
        let res = await run_cmd('xxxx')
        res = parse_first_res(res)
        res = await run_cmd('zzz' + res)
        res = parse_second_res('xxyy' + res)
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS is essentially single threaded. So as long as the code is synchronous no parallel processing can happen so you are safe.

However if the code is not synchronous (e.g. you do some database calls) then you need some sort of locking/semaphore. There's no escape.

Also note that locks/semaphores **do not** guarantee that a function will be called only once. It only guarantees that no parallel processing will happen. To ensure that the function is called only once you need some additional flag and `if` statement.

> Cause as a node user, I am not very happy to touch this sort of "multithread" thing.

This is not about multi or single threading. It is about parallel processing. It doesn't matter whether you are node user or not. You will have to deal with race conditions at some point.

Comment: I updated the question. I do want a "non-parallel process".

Comment: @J.R. Another option is to call `run_cmd` at the app's start if you don't have to run it again. Otherwise you'll need locking. That's exactly what locks are for: to restrict parallel processing.